# Is it possible to start an Android app without launching an Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, launch

Specifically, I am looking for a way to prevent the "black screen" from showing up when I run my app.

The app just runs a quick program whenever it is pressed but since it is linked to an Activity, it loads up a layout (black).  I know I could do a widget but I need it to be in the launcher....

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can set an `Activity` to have a theme which makes it invisible although I don't particularly like the idea. You don't go into things in-depth but what you're describing really goes against good design principles. If the user has to start your app in the same way as any other using the 'launcher' then they should at least get some visual feedback that it really did start and completed its task. Having a totally anonymous/invisible process goes against the way user-activated software should work.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you however in this case I do not :)  And there is feedback onscreen that it ran so the user knows it works.  It is really only a cosmetic thing that I would like to change.  Flashing a black screen looks tacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the black screen by adding

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

To your activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml

eg:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To have an icon in the launcher, you need to have the right intent-filter tag in your Android Manifest.

One way to avoid doing it for an Activity maybe you could try to add the intent-filter for a service instead...

I have no idea whether it would work, but may be worth a try...

Comment: Hmm...I don't think a service will really fit my needs.  All I really need is my app to run the code...just not in an Activity so it creates that layout.  Perhaps a way to prevent the layout from being created?  Or a way to interrupt it (run the code before the layout and call finish())?